# How to insert function address into hashtable?

Tags: c, function, hashtable

I want to save some functions into hashtable, the key is integer(some id), the value is function(or address?). My question is, how to store them in hashtable, so I can get a function  by key?
The hashtable insert function is like:

```
int ht_insert(ht_table *ht, void *key, size_t key_len, void *value, size_t value_len)

int func(void *){...}
```

My code is:

```
ht_insert(ht_tab, &myid, sizeof(myid), &func, sizeof(func));
```

and it doesn't work well.

-----------------------More details below----------------

1.The hashtable can be set to COPY or REFERENCE mode, I choose COPY mode(both key and value).
2.In fact I use function pointer as parameter, my original post may confused somebody. So I put some more codes here:

```
typedef int (*request_callback)(void *request); //typedef a function pointer

int add_callback_by_id(int id, request_callback cb)
{
...
    ht_insert(ht_tab, &id, sizeof(id), cb, sizeof(request_callback));
...
}

//here, pointer of func is passed to add_callback_by_id
add_callback_by_id(request_id, &func);

//
if ((cb = ht_lookup(ht_tab, &id, sizeof(id))) != null)
{
....
    (*(request_callback)cb)(request); //crashed here!
....
}
```

Finally, I use user694733's solution, by define a wrapper structure. It works!

```
typedef struct _callback_obj
{
    request_callback cb;
}callback_obj;

int add_callback_by_id(int id, request_callback cb)
{
    callback_obj cb_obj;
...
    cb_obj.cb = cb;
    ht_insert(ht_tab, &id, sizeof(id), &cb_obj, sizeof(callback_obj));
...
}

//
if ((pcb_obj = ht_lookup(ht_tab, &id, sizeof(id))) != null)
{
....
    (*(request_callback)pcb->cb)(request); //works, ^-^!
....
}
```

Although it works, but not convenience.

Comment: what you mean by `it doesn't work well.` ?

Comment: @abasu he means *at all*

Comment: What sort of error are you getting? Is it a compile error where the compiler says you've done something illegally? Is it a runtime error where it compiles fine but doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: I can get value(something,maybe not a function address) by key, but (*value)(...) crash @abasu

Comment: It's crashed, not compile problem.@jingtao

Comment: And you have typecasted the "value" to the correct function type? (Tip: Using `typedef` will help a lot here.)

Comment: Standard: "The sizeof operator can be applied to a pointer to a function, but shall not be applied directly to a function." - I'm surprised your `sizeof(func)` code even compiles.  Have you compared the value you get back out of the hash table to the one you put in?  Do they match?

Comment: @TonyD I concur, and can only hope the explanation in my answer make sense.

Comment: @WhoZCraig: it's one possible explanation... can't do anything but guess with such an uninformative question.  geniuslinchao - you should look into the implementation or examples to confirm Craig's suspicions.

Comment: @TonyD agreed. I could be totally out to lunch on the copy-by-address determination, but its the only one that makes sense to me given the size parameter. If the caller could just stash their own `void*` the size parameter wouldn't be needed. The curiosity is going to eat at me for awhile now.

Comment: @WhozCraig: agreed the sizes are unusual... could be aimed to make this more generic though - for variable-length string keys and data, or even some kind of C-style polymorphism.  Presumably the hashing and key comparison functions were specified earlier and stored in the `ht_table`, or some very generic byte-wise hashing and `memcmp` approach is taken.  The memory ownership semantics you postulate are pretty horrible as an API design, but - particularly if this is in-house corporate software - easy enough to imagine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear your hash table stores both the key *and* value by address (and requires a size therein for each). You're already storing your id by address. This is one way you can store your function pointer by address as well:

```
int (*myfunc)(void*) = &foo;

ht_insert(ht_tab, &myid, sizeof(myid), &myfunc, sizeof(myfunc));
```

**Explanation**

Storing a proc address as written in to this hash table is not going to do what you think it will. , *Its a code address*. Specifying a `sizeof()` (which shouldn't even work) will simply tell the hash table to goto that code address and copy out the specified size in bytes, storing that as the value. If the actual *passed* pointer *were the pointer* being stored, it would work, but then the size-parameter would also be useless. I'm quite-convinced this is a copy-by-address hash table, and as such, the value you need to pass is the *address* of a function pointer; *not* a simple function address. Without the exact function prototype for your value *retrieval* function I cannot show you how to get the function pointer back out and use it.

Note: I'm quite-sure the hash table doesn't care if your local variables like `myid` and `myfunc` go out of scope, and will happily invoke UB (at least on the key) trying to use data that is no longer valid. So i would suggest you either make them dynamic or otherwise ensure the data for keys and values you provide lives *at least* as long as your hash table.

---

**Update** (after OP addendum.1 to question)

Per code from the OP:

```
typedef int (*request_callback)(void *request); //typedef a function pointer

int add_callback_by_id(int id, request_callback cb)
{
...
    // This is wrong, but very close to correct
    ht_insert(ht_tab, &id, sizeof(id), cb, sizeof(request_callback));
...
}
```

The above should look like this:

```
int add_callback_by_id(int id, request_callback cb)
{
...
    // Pay note to the & operator. The change in sizeof() param is advisable
    ht_insert(ht_tab, &id, sizeof(id), &cb, sizeof(cb));
...
}
```

The retrieval and usage should look like this:

```
request_callback* ppfn = NULL; // note pointer-to-pointer-to-function

if ((ppfn = ht_lookup(ht_tab, &id, sizeof(id))) != null)
{
    (*ppfn)(request);
}
```

**Example**

The following rather trivial program demonstrates the above technique. Because I have no access to the OP's hash-table implementation, I'm afraid this is about as simple as I can make it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// these are normally in the hash table.
void *data;
size_t len;

typedef void (*callback_proc)(void*);

void set_callback(callback_proc cb)
{
    data = malloc(sizeof(cb));
    memcpy(data, &cb, sizeof(cb));
}

void *get_callback()
{
    return data;
}

// simple implementation. does nothing
void my_callback(void* pv)
{
    printf("My_callback called!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // invoke our inserter function
    set_callback(my_callback);

    // retrieval. note the pointer-to-pointer-to-function
    callback_proc* ppfn = get_callback();
    (*ppfn)(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
My_callback called!
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, it was more complicated way to do the same thing, as you pointed out.

Comment: @user694733 I suspect it should work as both of us think, but I think the OP is awol at this point, so we may never know.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for your answer. I tried but still not work. I gave more details to my question, may you can help me.

Comment: @geniuslinchao I've updated the answer to hopefully point you to where your mistakes were made. There is no functional difference to what user694733 demonstrated, so I suspected it was in the setup and retrieval code, and I was right. See the updates to the answer above, which are quite literally the best I can do in explaining how it should be done.